# General Application Design - Events + Async

Tags: modeling

I have an issue with designing my application.

1. On my login form, I fire off an event in my ViewModel that's handled in the View (it displays a progress bar).
2. Then I query the database
3. Based on the query result I fire off an event from my ViewModel whose handler displays a message based on the result

The problem is when the query executes so fast that the (async) event handler doesn't even get to initialize the progress bar before the second event gets fired. The second event handler registers that there are no progress dialogues open so it doesn't try to close the open one before displaying the message. And when the user acknowledges the message, he is left with a indeterminate progress dialog which blocks the rest of the UI.

What design pattern should I utilize to avoid this race condition?

Comment: Initiate the progress bar before querying the database so always have a listener?

Comment: @ZoffDino I probably didn't phrase my question correctly. I initiate the progress bar before querying. But the listener doesn't complete before the second event fires (which prevents the progress bar from closing)